# Unable to create a ECS capacity provider by aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Creating AWS ECS Capacity Provider on command line and it reports error as below:

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider --name="abc-perf3-$(date "+ %F-%H%M%S")" --auto-scaling-group-provider=abc-perf3 managedScaling=ENABLED managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED, managedScaling=ENABLED
```

I did try with **--** option as well but that does not work either.

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider --name="abc-perf3-$(date "+ %F-%H%M%S")" --auto-scaling-group-provider=abc-perf3 --managedScaling=ENABLED --managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --managedScaling=ENABLED, --managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED
```

I do not wish to use json file (json example given here, https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-ecs-developer-guide/blob/97febdb027cd297d915c1a6ae14b813e671d0dcc/doc_source/tutorial-cluster-auto-scaling-cli.md)

I want to create a capacity provider by passing arguments on command line but pass arguments on command line, how to achieve that?

**P.S:** Update after I tried the answer.

Command below:

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider --name="abc-perf3-$(date "+ %F-%H%M%S")" --auto-scaling-group-provider="abc-perf3" managedScaling={status=ENABLED,targetCapacity=75}, managedTerminationProtection=DISABLE
```

**Error message:**

```
Unknown options: managedScaling=targetCapacity=75,, managedTerminationProtection=DISABLED, managedScaling=status=ENABLED,
```

P.P.S : Update 2. Still not working.

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider --name="abc-dev3-$(date "+%F-%H%M%S")" --auto-scaling-group-provider "abc-dev3" managedScaling "{status=ENABLED,targetCapacity=75}",managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: {status=ENABLED,targetCapacity=75},managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED, managedScaling
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct command which worked is as below:

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider --name "abc-dev-$(date "+%F-%H%M%S")" --auto-scaling-group-provider "autoScalingGroupArn="arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:autoScalingGroup:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:autoScalingGroupName/abc-dev",managedScaling={status=ENABLED,targetCapacity=75},managedTerminationProtection=DISABLED"
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the AWS CLI, you can simplify the entry of json structures by using **shorthand syntax**.

> The AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) can accept many of its option parameters in JSON format. However, it can be tedious to enter large JSON lists or structures on the command line. To make this easier, the AWS CLI also supports a shorthand syntax that enables a simpler representation of your option parameters than using the full JSON format.

The format is a comma-separated list of key-value pairs.

```
--option key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3
```

For your command the correct syntax would be something like:

```
aws ecs create-capacity-provider
 --name="abc-perf3-$(date "+ %F-%H%M%S")"
 --auto-scaling-group-provider managedScaling={status=string,targetCapacity=integer,minimumScalingStepSize=integer,maximumScalingStepSize=integer}, 
managedTerminationProtection=ENABLED
```

See [Using Shorthand Syntax with the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-shorthand.html)  and [AWS CLI Command Reference for ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-capacity-provider.html)

Comment: Sir, I tried, unfortunately still does not work for me. I have updated my post with what I tried after your response.

Comment: You are not following the syntax correctly. In your example of option `--auto-scaling-group-provider=`, both the documentation and my example show the seperator to be a space, not an equal sign. Please review carefully. I have provided the correct syntax, which follows the cli reference.

Comment: `--auto-scaling-group-provider="abc-perf3"` does not conform to the command syntax shown.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It didn't work even with the syntax, perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Sir, I posted the command which worked for me without any issue.

Comment: Yes great! That is the correct syntax, as shown by example in my answer and in the command reference.